# Linq query for count outside join

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, group-by, grouping, inner-join

I have two tables 
`PatientEncounterDemo` and `PatientMaster`

`PatientEncounterDemo`:

```
PateientID(F.K int),
DoctorId( F.K int),
ProcedureName



PatientMaster:

PatientId(P.K identity)
PatientFirstName(varchar(50)),
PatientLastName(varchar(50)),
PatientDOB
```

I need to extract PatientName(patientFirstName_+patientLastName),patientDOB,and Count of procedures assigned to a paticular patient(a patient can have many procedures assigned to it)

I have wrote SQL query for that result as:

```
//This puts the join inside count-

select distinct  PatientFirstName+ ' ' + PatientLastName as PatientName,PatientDOB,COUNT(ProcedureName) as [Proc Count] from
(
select distinct  p.PatientFirstName,p.PatientLastName,p.PatientDOB,e.ProcedureName
from PatientMaster p,PatientEncounterDemo e 
where p.PatientId=e.PatientId and e.DoctorId=1
)as mytable group by PatientFirstName,PatientLastName,PatientDOB
```

But,I am struggling to do that through linq query.Please suggest some way..!!

Comment: Which O/RM tool are you using?

Comment: @Steven I am not using any tool as such..I am just using Linq to sql(.dbml) classes provided in .net 4.0

Comment: LINQ to SQL is an Object Relational mapper.

Comment: @Steven ok..I understand that..But then is it related to my problem?

Comment: It is related, because the LINQ support of your O/RM tool is always a subset of what you can do with LINQ to Objects, and it differs per O/RM framework. So the given answer could be different.

Comment: @Steven ok...I go that but do find any solution for this senario..because none of the codes given below is giving the correct result..:(

Comment: But the given answers might give you some ideas how to solve this. We're not here to do your job as a developer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a (almost) one-to-one mapping from your SQL to LINQ:

```
var myTable = (
    from encounter in db.PatientEncounterDemos
    where encounter.Doctor.Id == 1
    let patient = encounter.Patient
    select    new 
    {
        patient.FirstName, 
        patient.LastName,         
        patient.DOB,
        encounter.ProcedureName
    })
    .Distinct();

var results =
    from item in myTable
    group item by new { item.FirstName, item.LastName, item.DOB } into g
    select new 
    { 
        PatientName = g.Key.FirstName + " " + g.Key.LastName, 
        g.Key.DOB, 
        ProcCount = g.Count() 
    };
```

But this would be easier to follow:

```
var myTable = (
    from encounter in db.PatientEncounterDemos
    where encounter.Doctor.Id == 1
    select new { encounter.Patient, encounter.ProcedureName })
    .Distinct();

var results =
    from item in myTable
    group item by item into g
    select new 
    { 
        PatientName =
            g.Key.Patient.FirstName + " " + g.Key.Patient.LastName, 
        g.Key.DOB, 
        ProcCount = g.Count() 
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this should achieve what you are after:

```
var patientProcedureCounts =
    from master in PatientMasters
    select new
    {
        master.PatientId,
        PatientName = master.PatientFirstName + " " +
            master.PatientLastName,
        master.PatientDOB,
        ProcedureCount = (from demo in PatientEncounterDemos 
            where demo.PatientId == master.PatientId &&
                demo.DoctorId == 1 
            select 1).Count()
    };
```

This will select all `PatientMasters`, then select all `PatientEncounterDemos` for the `PatientId` and `DoctorId`. Finally it will use the master detail and the count of the demo's for that patient to construct a new anonymous type which can be enumerated like so:

```
foreach(var procedureInfo in patientProcedureCounts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Patient {0} born on {1} had {2} procedures", 
        procedureInfo.PatientName, procedureInfo.PatientDOB, procedureInfo.ProcedureCount);
}
```

The following is the SQL generated by LINQPad which looks close enough to what you are after:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) SET @p0 = ' '
DECLARE @p1 Int SET @p1 = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[PatientId], ([t0].[PatientFirstName] + @p0) + [t0].[PatientLastName] AS [PatientName], [t0].[PatientDOB], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [PatientEncounterDemo] AS [t1]
    WHERE ([t1].[PatientId] = [t0].[PatientId]) AND ([t1].[DoctorId] = @p1)
    ) AS [ProcedureCount]
FROM [PatientMaster] AS [t0]
```

Comment: Sorry to say this but this code gives error when the compiler reads through the patientProcedureCounts in FOREACH loop...
The error says:Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'.

Comment: Sorry about that @RahulRanjan I've created a database the same schema as yours and updated my query to work properly. I've tested this in LINQPad and it worked for me :)

Comment: ya i can feel that it would have worked in your case...
but yes,even I my case with some corrections in your code..I achieved what I wanted..So,Thanks a lot for your replies..!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your SQL (hopefully should work).  This should be easier to produce the LINQ from.

```
SELECT 
    p.PatientFirstName + ' ' + p.PatientLastName as PatientName
    p.PatientDOB,
    COUNT(e.ProcudureName) AS [Proc Count]
FROM 
    PatientMaster p
    INNER JOIN PatientEncounterDemo e ON p.PatientId = e.PatientId
WHERE
    e.DoctorId=1
GROUP BY
    p.PatientFirstName,
    p.PatientLastName,
    p.PatientDOB
```

Comment: No.seems you have not understood my code..this editing has changed its meaning..I am first storing the join result inside a temporary table and then appliying count and group by on that result..
This code would simply give error as I have checked on my machine...!!
Here

Answer (score 0):

Finally with the support of all your answers I got the exact result by this query.

Firstly I am performed inner join along with the where condition on the db.

Then I have grouped the result by following multiple columns and performed count on that group.

My Linq query:

```
 var myTable = (
          from master in MyDataContext.PatientMasters
          join encounter in MyDataContext.PatientEncounterDemos
          on master.PatientId equals encounter.PatientId
          where encounter.DoctorId == doctorID
          select new { master.PatientFirstName, master.PatientLastName, master.PatientDOB, encounter.ProcedureName })
          .Distinct();

      var results =
          from item in myTable
          group item by new { item.PatientFirstName, item.PatientLastName, item.PatientDOB } into grp
          select new
          {
              PatientName =
                  grp.Key.PatientFirstName + " " + grp.Key.PatientLastName,
              grp.Key.PatientDOB,
              ProcCount = grp.Count()
          };
```

and now I applied Foreach loop to get the result to a list..!!
Thanks to all...!!!!